# Getting horrendous accuracy with tensorflow on easy classification data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, perceptron

I'm starting out learning how to use tensorflow. So, I started with the most basic tutorial provided [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network_raw.py).

The example trains the two layer perceptron on mnist data. I decided to replace this with my own data. So, I created a method that generates 2-d data belonging to one of four classes (see very simple implementation, [method called get_data here](https://github.com/ryu577/DeepLearning/blob/master/CycloidalDat.py)). The classes are quite clearly linearly separable (see figure below). So, I expect any classifier to knock this out of the park.

I then [modify the tensorflow sample](https://github.com/ryu577/DeepLearning/blob/master/train_perceptron.py) so that it reads in my data instead.

And the results are just horrible. The loss seems to not be correlated with the accuracy at all, which varies wildly across the training progresses.

Is it obvious to anyone what I might be missing? The modifications I made are really simple and I have reviewed them many times.

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 2167311.5000, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 100, Minibatch Loss= 19227.4277, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 200, Minibatch Loss= 5008.3398, Training Accuracy= 0.180
Step 300, Minibatch Loss= 1909.1743, Training Accuracy= 0.461
Step 400, Minibatch Loss= 1811.5497, Training Accuracy= 0.398
Step 500, Minibatch Loss= 2363.8840, Training Accuracy= 0.414
Step 600, Minibatch Loss= 2374.1931, Training Accuracy= 0.195
Step 700, Minibatch Loss= 173.2211, Training Accuracy= 0.352
Step 800, Minibatch Loss= 1286.1042, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 900, Minibatch Loss= 560.9091, Training Accuracy= 0.023
Step 1000, Minibatch Loss= 163.1450, Training Accuracy= 0.195
Step 1100, Minibatch Loss= 412.8525, Training Accuracy= 0.023
Step 1200, Minibatch Loss= 155.7486, Training Accuracy= 0.094
Step 1300, Minibatch Loss= 137.8443, Training Accuracy= 0.078
Step 1400, Minibatch Loss= 59.5813, Training Accuracy= 0.062
Step 1500, Minibatch Loss= 74.8706, Training Accuracy= 0.180
Step 1600, Minibatch Loss= 7.7829, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 1700, Minibatch Loss= 18.4251, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 1800, Minibatch Loss= 76.1630, Training Accuracy= 0.211
Step 1900, Minibatch Loss= 2147.1362, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 2000, Minibatch Loss= 8275.0098, Training Accuracy= 0.242
Step 2100, Minibatch Loss= 36986.7539, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 2200, Minibatch Loss= 2482.1418, Training Accuracy= 0.164
Step 2300, Minibatch Loss= 8919.1445, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 2400, Minibatch Loss= 2694.6621, Training Accuracy= 0.172
Step 2500, Minibatch Loss= 262.8948, Training Accuracy= 0.172
Step 2600, Minibatch Loss= 655.5334, Training Accuracy= 0.148
Step 2700, Minibatch Loss= 278.0427, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 2800, Minibatch Loss= 2314.9653, Training Accuracy= 0.242
Step 2900, Minibatch Loss= 570.7736, Training Accuracy= 0.180
Step 3000, Minibatch Loss= 4217.2334, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 3100, Minibatch Loss= 1161.3817, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 3200, Minibatch Loss= 2473.6438, Training Accuracy= 0.234
Step 3300, Minibatch Loss= 2483.4707, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 3400, Minibatch Loss= 720.1823, Training Accuracy= 0.070
Step 3500, Minibatch Loss= 1411.0126, Training Accuracy= 0.188
Step 3600, Minibatch Loss= 1034.0898, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 3700, Minibatch Loss= 2143.2910, Training Accuracy= 0.258
Step 3800, Minibatch Loss= 2471.9592, Training Accuracy= 0.242
Step 3900, Minibatch Loss= 932.8969, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 4000, Minibatch Loss= 2762.5869, Training Accuracy= 0.180
Step 4100, Minibatch Loss= 2132.0295, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 4200, Minibatch Loss= 6322.4692, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Step 4300, Minibatch Loss= 6657.2842, Training Accuracy= 0.242
Step 4400, Minibatch Loss= 343629.0312, Training Accuracy= 0.195
Step 4500, Minibatch Loss= 19370.7188, Training Accuracy= 0.234
Step 4600, Minibatch Loss= 1008.6259, Training Accuracy= 0.227
Step 4700, Minibatch Loss= 952.9269, Training Accuracy= 0.125
Step 4800, Minibatch Loss= 390.7108, Training Accuracy= 0.211
Step 4900, Minibatch Loss= 846.1492, Training Accuracy= 0.188
Step 5000, Minibatch Loss= 218.7473, Training Accuracy= 0.250
Optimization Finished!
Testing Accuracy: 0.3275
```

[image: Radially separable data with four classes generated]

Answer (score 1):

Your learning rate is quite large; common values are closer to the range of 0.001-0.01 (although, this can vary on your specific task). Additionally, you might want to reduce the learning rate over time (what is called "learning rate decay" (more in [Andrey Karpathy's great lecture](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/)).

Also, training for only 5000 iterations might not be what you are looking for. Oftentimes, something like "overfitting" prevents you from accurately learning a *general* representation. This means, you are very good at recognizing (and classifying) your previously seen trianing data, but not so good at classifying unseen data. 
For that, it is good practice to use a third dataset for validation (~size of test set). This validation set is then used to see how good the trained model performs on withhold data. You would evaluate after every 100th iteration or so, and then see how the loss changes on this dataset.

A common technique is then "early stopping", which means you stop with the training process once your algorithm does not improve on the test set anymore. A nice visualization, with a closely related context, is shown in [this Stackexchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209359/meaning-of-cross-validation).

Lastly, 256 neurons are quite a lot, and might not even be necessary in your case. I couldn't quite tell how many dimensions your input has, but generally you should be good with around 16 neurons per layer (maybe experiment with it, and see how good the network performs with different sizes).

A lot of the results are purely coming from knowing which parameters to set, so good luck!